# Zend 2 model class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am learning the framework Zend 2. I am stuck on a error which says that the system can't find the model class. Below here the message.

> Fatal error: Class 'Album\Model\Album' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zend2_tut/module/Album/Module.php on line 47

The code I used is from the tutorial from zend 2.

Codes are below here:

**Module.php**

```
namespace Album;

// Models
use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;

// Db
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

// Zend
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array (
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array (
                'namespaces' => array (
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
             'factories' => array(
                 'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                     $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
                 },
                 'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                     return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                 },
             ),
         );
    }
}
```

**Album.php**

```
namespace Album\Model;

class Album
{
    public $id;
    public $artist;
    public $title;

    public function exchangeArray($data) {
        $this->id = (!empty($data["id"])) ? $data["id"] : null;
        $this->artist = (!empty($data["artist"])) ? $data["artist"] : null;
        $this->title = (!empty($data["title"])) ? $data["title"] : null;
    }
}
```

Below the file tree

### Module

```
Album
```

---

```
      Model
      ------
            Album.php
      Module.php
```

I hope I can solve this because I don't know where the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Module.php you need to do this below change

```
 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface {
```

To

```
class Module {
```

You no need to add these to link as well

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

without these feature autoloader libraries you module will work fine.